# The equivalent of Fiddler SOAP request/response stored in database

Tags: wcf, web-services, soap

I write a lot of WCF services to other services. I have had trouble with getting Fiddler to log the SOAP messages before but now I have that working. But my boss wants something without Fiddler at all where I can take the SOAP message going out and the one coming in logged to the database. I have looked a lot at WCF Logging and Diagnostics and extending it with Database Source Listener but I cant find an implementation of a Database Source Listener to use.

I don't think that's what he even wants. He wants the equivalent of Fiddler's SOAP request/response displays written to the database. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You have two possibilities:

1. Write custom [WCF Trace Listener](http://www.i-avington.com/Posts/Post/creating-a-custom-trace-listener-for-wcf), calling database procedure to store logging data:

   ```
   public class AsyncMSMQTraceListener : TraceListener
   {
       public override void TraceData(TraceEventCache eventCache, string source,
                                      TraceEventType eventType, int id, object data)
       {
          // eventType like for example TraceEventType.Information
          var message = data.ToString();

          // Here call datbase save log with message              
       }


       public override void Write(string message)
       {
       }

       public override void WriteLine(string message)
       {
       }
   }
   ```

   but in this way you'll get trace messages, where request/response is only a part of it.
2. Write custom [Message Inspector](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2011/04/23/wcf-extensibility-message-inspectors.aspx) class:

   ```
   public class ConsoleOutputMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
   {
       public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
       {
           MessageBuffer buffer = request.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
           request = buffer.CreateMessage();

           // Here you can use buffer.CreateMessage().ToString()

           return null;
       }

       public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
       {
           MessageBuffer buffer = reply.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
           reply = buffer.CreateMessage();

           // here you can use buffer.CreateMessage().ToString()
       }
   }
   ```

***Note***: Regardless which method you choose, I would suggest to make some kind of an asynchronous call to the database to not block normal service flow.

Comment: That's the part I don't get - the async write to the database. Can you show an example of this?

Comment: I mean, you should not call stored procedures synchronously because it will block till write to the database will finish. It might be as simple as using Task: `var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoYourDatabaseAction());`

Comment: My WCF service is actually calling another service. Does that make it a Client Message Inspector?

Comment: Yes, from this perspective client message inspector is needed.

Comment: Also, I need a behavior so that I can apply the MessageInspector

Comment: I can't get it working. I need to show my implementation of the Client Message Inspector and the Behavior. Do I edit my topic or start another one?

Comment: @user2471435 you should probably open a new one because it will be a question specific to Client Message Inspector usage. But double check if there is no similar question/answers already on SO.

Comment: OK, its here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20642577/trouble-getting-clientmessageinspector-to-work