# Trouble Getting ClientMessageInspector to work

Tags: wcf

This is a continuation of the Stack Overflow topic [The equivalent of Fiddler SOAP Request/Response in the Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620149/the-equivalent-of-fiddler-soap-request-response-stored-in-database). I implemented a ClientMessageInspector like so:

```
 public class RREMOutputMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
    {
        private string _connStringProd = String.Empty;
 public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
            MessageBuffer buffer = reply.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
            reply = buffer.CreateMessage();

            _connStringProd = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RREM_Gilbane_ProdConnectionString"].ToString();
            NREMGilbaneTableAdapters.SOAPMessagesTableAdapter soapMessages =
                new NREMGilbaneTableAdapters.SOAPMessagesTableAdapter();
            soapMessages.Connection.ConnectionString = _connStringProd;

            string replyString = buffer.CreateMessage().ToString();
            soapMessages.Insert(replyString, DateTime.Now, "Interface12", "Interface12", "", "", "", "");
        }

        public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel)
        {
            MessageBuffer buffer = request.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
            request = buffer.CreateMessage();

            _connStringProd = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RREM_Gilbane_ProdConnectionString"].ToString();
            NREMGilbaneTableAdapters.SOAPMessagesTableAdapter soapMessages =
                new NREMGilbaneTableAdapters.SOAPMessagesTableAdapter();
            soapMessages.Connection.ConnectionString = _connStringProd;

            string requestString = buffer.CreateMessage().ToString();
            soapMessages.Insert(requestString, DateTime.Now, "Interface12", "Interface12", "", "", "", "");
            return null;
        }
```

Then I implemented a behavior for the inspector:

```
public class RREMBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
    {
        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
            RREMOutputMessageInspector inspector = new RREMOutputMessageInspector();
            clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(inspector);
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

Finally in my WCF Service, I have the following when making a call to the other web service:

```
 documentSvcResponse = client.retrieveDocument(authHeader, retrieveDoc);
                    client.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new RREMBehavior());
```

I don't hit any breakpoints in my Inspector. Are you supposed to be able to set breakpoints in an inspector. Also, this web service has a loop implemented where the above 2 lines are being executed multiple times. Is that the problem? I see no evidence that this is working, Help again please!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should. Have you added the endpointbehavior and extensions to your web.config file? Have a look at this msdn article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector(v=vs.110).aspx

I don't really understand your question regarding the loop? But it sound a bit strange.

Comment: I'm sorry. I can't make heads or tails out of that example in that page. It also seems incorrect as a copy of the message is not stored so isn't it gone?